# Как вставить #якорь в url по клику?

Tags: javascript, html5-history-api

Посоветуйте, пож-та, где почитать поподробнее о том, как реализуется подстановка #якорей из ссылок в url адресной строки браузера при помощи BOM?
Необходимо иметь возможность дать человеку ссылку с якорем вида: www.yandex.ru/page1#yakor

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто при клике вызвать такое:

```
element.href = location.hash
```

Answer (score 1):

Страница обновляется к блоку по якорю спускается. Тестировать лучше на своем проекте.

Рабочий код:

```js
$("ol li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var param = $(this).attr("href");
    var url = window.location.pathname;

    location.reload();
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, url + param);

  });

var url_param = window.location.hash;

if (url_param != "" && typeof url_param !== "undefined") {
  var body = $("html, body");
  var div = $(url_param).offset();

  body.stop().animate({
    scrollTop: div.top
  }, 500, 'swing', function() {

  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

  <body>
    <h1>URL</h1>

    <h2 id="contents">Оглавление</h2>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="#history">История</a></li>
      <li><a href="#structure">Структура URL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#encoding">Кодирование URL</a></li>
    </ol>

    <h2 id="history">История</h2>
    <p>URL был изобретён Тимом Бернерсом-Ли в 1990 году в стенах Европейского совета по ядерным исследованиям в Женеве, Швейцария. URL стал фундаментальной инновацией в Интернете.</p>
    <p>Изначально URL предназначался для обозначения мест расположения ресурсов (чаще всего файлов) во Всемирной паутине. Сейчас URL применяется для обозначения адресов почти всех ресурсов Интернета. Стандарт URL закреплён в документе RFC 1738, прежняя версия
      была определена в RFC 1630.</p>
    <p>Сейчас URL позиционируется как часть более общей системы идентификации ресурсов URI, сам термин URL постепенно уступает место более широкому термину URI. Стандарт URL регулируется организацией IETF и её подразделениями.Появление адресов URL стало
      существенным нововведением в Интернете. Однако с момента его изобретения и по сей день стандарт URL обладает серьёзным недостатком — в нём можно использовать только ограниченный набор символов, даже меньший, нежели в ASCII: латинские буквы, цифры
      и лишь некоторые знаки препинания. Если мы захотим использовать в URL символы кириллицы, или иероглифы, или, скажем, специфические символы французского языка, то нужные нам символы должны быть перекодированы особым образом.Появление адресов URL
      стало существенным нововведением в Интернете. Однако с момента его изобретения и по сей день стандарт URL обладает серьёзным недостатком — в нём можно использовать только ограниченный набор символов, даже меньший, нежели в ASCII: латинские буквы,
      цифры и лишь некоторые знаки препинания. Если мы захотим использовать в URL символы кириллицы, или иероглифы, или, скажем, специфические символы французского языка, то нужные нам символы должны быть перекодированы особым образом.</p>
    <a href="#contents">К оглавлению</a>

    <h2 id="structure">Структура URL</h2>
    <p>Изначально локатор URL был разработан как система для максимально естественного указания на местонахождения ресурсов в сети. Локатор должен был быть легко расширяемым и использовать лишь ограниченный набор ASCII‐символов (к примеру, пробел никогда
      не применяется в URL). В связи с этим, возникла следующая традиционная форма записи URL:Появление адресов URL стало существенным нововведением в Интернете. Однако с момента его изобретения и по сей день стандарт URL обладает серьёзным недостатком
      — в нём можно использовать только ограниченный набор символов, даже меньший, нежели в ASCII: латинские буквы, цифры и лишь некоторые знаки препинания. Если мы захотим использовать в URL символы кириллицы, или иероглифы, или, скажем, специфические
      символы французского языка, то нужные нам символы должны быть перекодированы особым образом.Появление адресов URL стало существенным нововведением в Интернете. Однако с момента его изобретения и по сей день стандарт URL обладает серьёзным недостатком
      — в нём можно использовать только ограниченный набор символов, даже меньший, нежели в ASCII: латинские буквы, цифры и лишь некоторые знаки препинания. Если мы захотим использовать в URL символы кириллицы, или иероглифы, или, скажем, специфические
      символы французского языка, то нужные нам символы должны быть перекодированы особым образом.</p>

    <a href="#contents">К оглавлению</a>

    <h2 id="encoding">Кодирование URL</h2>
    <p>Появление адресов URL стало существенным нововведением в Интернете. Однако с момента его изобретения и по сей день стандарт URL обладает серьёзным недостатком — в нём можно использовать только ограниченный набор символов, даже меньший, нежели в ASCII:
      латинские буквы, цифры и лишь некоторые знаки препинания. Если мы захотим использовать в URL символы кириллицы, или иероглифы, или, скажем, специфические символы французского языка, то нужные нам символы должны быть перекодированы особым образом.</p>
    <a href="#contents">К оглавлению</a>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идёт об одностраничном приложении, то надо подписаться на [`hashchange`](//developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange).
Ну и при открытии страницы вызвать соответствующий обработчик.